# Windows Service not writing text file after installation in Windows Service System

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, windows-server-2008, text-files

I have made a windows Service that contains a Socket Connection Code.As per the code after installation of this windows Service and after starting,it should write some Messages into the text file but i am not able to see any of my messages into text file.While in my local PC which contains Windows 7 ,my this service is able to write into the text file.
Here is my code..

```
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Before Connection !");
                }

                client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), intport));

                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Connected To Machine !");
                }

            }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the error here.
                client.Close();

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Connection Error !");
                }

                continue;
            }
```

So my doubt is why is my Service not able to write into Server text file while it is doing in my local System.Also there are other text files in the server PC that is getting messages from other Windows Services made from someone else.Why is this happening in my case?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `textfileSaveLocation` absolute or relative path? If it's a relative path, it will store the file somewhere in the process' working directory, which for windows services is C:\Windows\System32\ by default (%windir%\System32\ to be more precise) - you can find the path by calling `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` static property.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan"D:/logs/response.txt" this is the path where i am trying to write..How can i use your suggestion.

Comment: If you use an absolute path, this should not be an issue. In that case I suggest following the points in raja's answer (points 1-3).

Comment: @HonzaBrestan the account is LocalSystem Only,the folder path is correct,and i am running the service as admin privileges

Comment: Process Monitor (available from MS web site) is the essential troubleshooting tool for this class of problem.

Comment: If you have admin rights, put a call to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in your `OnStart()` callback.  When you start the service in DEBUG mode, you should be prompted to enter a debug session.  Put a breakpoint in the code you referenced above and see what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

Check the following:

1. The account running the windows service has write permissions on the folder path.
2. The folder path is correct.
3. You might be running the service as Admin on your local box, hence it has all privileges.
4. Also in your Exception block, ensure the ex.ToString() is logged. It gives a lot of info.
5. Your `client.Close()` can also raise an exception. Take care of that scenario.

If there are file access issues, then put an uber try/catch block and try to write the text file on a public folder first where you know Everyone has access.

Comment: Agreed (+1) Should really try to get client to implement IDisposable to solve number 5.

Answer (score 0):

In **serviceProcessInstaller** you should set the Account property to **LocalSystem**. This will cause the service to be installed and to run on a local service account.